# Crossfade to and fro between two Imageviews

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have managed to crossfade from ImagView1 to Imagview 2 using the code below. I put function "fade" to iron1.

```
    public void fade(View view)
{
    ImageView img1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iron1);
    img1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    ImageView img2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iron2);
    img2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}
```

Now, when I crossfade into 2nd image ie; iron2. Now, I want to crossfade back into the 1st image so, I created this code putting "fade" onClick on iron1 and fade2 on iron2.

```
    public void fade(View view)
{
    ImageView img1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iron1);
    img1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    ImageView img2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iron2);
    img2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}

public void fade2(View view)
{
    ImageView img2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iron2);
    img2.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    ImageView img1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iron1);
    img1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}
```

Now, the application loads and when I click there is no transition from image1 to 2 even which was happening earlier. Any help? I think because both images overlap each other they are being clicked at the same time.

**Update**: I was able to crossfade through a button click though. Can anyone help me to do without button when clicking on image itself?

```
   public void fade3(View view)
   {

   ImageView img1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iron1);
   Log.i("Alpha", String.valueOf(img1.getAlpha()));
   ImageView img2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iron2);
   if(img1.getAlpha()==1)
   {
       Log.i("Alpha", String.valueOf(img1.getAlpha()));
       img1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
       img2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
   }

   else
   {
       img2.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
       img1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
   }
   }
```

Comment: Which layout you are using?

Comment: Relative layout

Comment: Use frame layout. And try it again

Comment: @Azharosws - Tried. same thing.